# Why does the to_Char(date, 'd') function simply ignoring the conditional logic in Oracle procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, to-char

I am trying to check the day of the performanceDate and only apply the discount if its a weekday.

//14/04/2018 Sat

```
v_performanceday VARCHAR(5);

SELECT PERFORMANCEDATE INTO v_performanceday FROM PERFORMANCE WHERE PERFORMANCEID = p_PerformanceID;
CASE
WHEN (to_char(v_performanceday, 'd') != '6' OR to_char(v_performanceday, 'd') != '7')
    THEN
    INSERT INTO DISCOUNT  (Reason, MembershipID, PerformanceID) 
    VALUES (p_Reason, p_MembershipID, p_PerformanceID)
    returning DiscountID into v_discountid;
    v_discountprice := 2.0;
ELSE
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, '***********Members only get discount on weekday performances!***************'); 
END CASE;
```

Right now, I am getting this error.

```
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "USER2.CREATE_NEW_BOOKING", line 56
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
       occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
       assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
       attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
       declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
       that values do not violate constraints.
```

But if I replace the first line data type to DATE, it applies discount regardless of if I insert the PerformanceID of Performance happening on Weekday or Weekend!

```
v_performanceday DATE;
```

Could anyone help me figure out why it's not applying the to_char function properly and simply ignoring it when other case statements around this are perfectly working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v_performancedate` should be a date -- that is the correct type.

Your logic is incorrect.  The `or` should be `and` . . . or better yet, `not in`:

```
CASE WHEN to_char(v_performanceday, 'd') not in ('6', '7')
```

Comment: Note, result of `TO_CHAR(..., 'D')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` settings. Better use `to_char(v_performanceday, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = american') not in ('sat', 'sun')`